# Yii2 Accordion - Первый таб сделать неактивным

Tags: yii2

```
echo Accordion::widget([
                'items' => [
                    [
                        'header' => 'Section 1',
                        'content' => 'Mauris mauris ante, blandit et, ultrices a, suscipit eget...',
                        'options' => ['tag' => 'div', 'active' => false],
                    ],
                    [
                        'header' => 'Section 2',
                        'headerOptions' => ['tag' => 'h3'],
                        'content' => 'Sed non urna. Phasellus eu ligula. Vestibulum sit amet purus...',
                        'options' => ['tag' => 'div'],
                    ],
                ],
                'options' => ['tag' => 'div'],
                'itemOptions' => ['tag' => 'div'],
                'headerOptions' => ['tag' => 'h2'],
                'clientOptions' => ['collapsible' => true],
            ]);
```

Подскажите пжл, как сделать первый таб не активным по умолчанию.В доках пвроде не написано, а вот в аккордеоне jquery есть опция active. Пробовал применять её, но видимо не в тех местах.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение - добавить в `'clientOptions'` опцию `'active' => false`, что бы получилось вот так:

```
'clientOptions' => ['collapsible' => true, 'active' => false],
```

Answer (score 1):

Если вы хотите сделать первый таб не активным, а второй активным:

```
'clientOptions' => ['active' => 1]
```